# Scrollbar in div always appearing at the bottom by default when content overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a web application where I have a message container (#messageContainer) that displays messages. I want the scrollbar inside this container to always appear at the bottom by default when the content overflows, providing a smooth chat-like experience.

[div image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY5xN.png)

I'd like to make a scrollbar similar to the one seen above.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images here. You were informed of this on previous questions you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

html file

```
 <body>
    <div id="messageContainer">
        <span>your messages</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Suppose CSS style

```
    #messageContainer{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Js Code

```
    const targetDiv = document.getElementById('messageContainer')
    targetDiv.scrollTo(0, targetDiv.scrollHeight)
```